# Storing .raw File Data as a Pointer Using C

Tags: c, image-processing, malloc, fread

I am attempting to read a '.raw' file which stores the contents of an image that was taken on a camera using C. I would like to store these contents into a `uint16_t *`.
In the following code I attempt to store this data into a pointer, using `fread()`, and then write this data into a test file, using `fwrite()`, to check if my data was correct.
However, when I write the file back it is completely black when I check it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ROW 2560
#define MAX_COL 2160

int main()
{
    char filename[32] = "image1.raw";
    FILE * image_raw = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(image_raw, 0, 2);
    long filesize = ftell(image_raw);
    
    /*READ IMAGE DATA*/
    uint16_t * image_data_ptr;
    image_data_ptr = (uint16_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*MAX_ROW*MAX_COL);
    fread(image_data_ptr, sizeof(uint16_t), filesize, image_raw);
    fclose(image_raw);
   
   
    /*TEST WRITING THE SAME DATA BACK INTO TEST RAW FILE*/
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("TEST.raw", "w");
    fwrite(image_data_ptr, sizeof(uint16_t), filesize, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted `filesize/2`. Also use binary mode (`"wb"`). Also you can check whether `fread` or `fwrite` returned any error.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. What is the purpose of using filesize/2? My file size is doubling everytime I write back so I think you're on to something.

Comment: You seeked to the end of the file to see how big it was, then tried to read it without seeking again.  How much do you think got read from the file?

Comment: why using `uint16_t`?

Comment: After seeking the input file to the end to get its size, you are not seeking back to the beginning of the file before reading the bytes. Also, don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) - `fseek(image_raw, 0, SEEK_END);` is easier to understand than `fseek(image_raw, 0, 2);`

Comment: @RMarms You are telling `fwrite` to write `filesize` number of `uint16_t`s (2 bytes each) but `filesize` was measured in bytes

Comment: Thank you all, not using fseek() was my issue.

Comment: Some side notes: casting the return of `malloc` is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965) in C, and `int main()` should really be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- lack of error handling.
- not seeking the input file back to offset 0 after seeking it to get its size.  Consider using `stat()` or equivalent to get the file size without having to seek the file at all.
- not dividing `filesize` by `sizeof(uint16_t)` when reading from the input file, or writing to the output file.  `filesize` is expressed in bytes, but `fread`/`fwrite` are expressed in number of items of a given size instead, and your items are not 1 byte in size.
- not opening the output file in binary mode.
- leaking the buffer you allocate.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char filename[32] = "image1.raw";

    FILE *image_raw = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!image_raw) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (fseek(image_raw, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't seek input file\n");
        fclose(image_raw);
        return -1;
    }

    long filesize = ftell(image_raw);
    if (filesize == -1L) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't get input file size\n");
        fclose(image_raw);
        return -1;
    }

    rewind(image_raw);

    long numSamples = filesize / sizeof(uint16_t);

    /*READ IMAGE DATA*/
    uint16_t *image_data_ptr = (uint16_t*) malloc(filesize);
    if (!image_data_ptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't allocate memory\n");
        fclose(image_raw);
        return -1;
    }

    size_t numRead = fread(image_data_ptr, sizeof(uint16_t), numSamples, image_raw);
    if (numRead != numSamples) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't read samples from file\n");
        free(image_data_ptr);
        fclose(image_raw);
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(image_raw);
   

    /*TEST WRITING THE SAME DATA BACK INTO TEST RAW FILE*/
    FILE *fp = fopen("TEST.raw", "wb");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open output file\n");
        free(image_data_ptr);
        return -1;
    }

    if (fwrite(image_data_ptr, sizeof(uint16_t), numSamples, fp) != numSamples) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't write to output file\n");
        fclose(fp);
        free(image_data_ptr);
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(image_data_ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is such a helpful answer. Your code worked exactly for what I wanted to do. I really appreciate the time you took to write this out and I definitely got a better understanding of file manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You have already a great answer and useful comments

anyway, consider that if you want to iterate over your file, loaded in memory as a whole, as an `array` of `unsigned words`:

- if the file size could be odd what to do at the last byte/word
- you may read the file as a whole in a single call, after having the file size determined
- `fstat()` is the normal way to get the file size
- get the file name from the command line as an argument is much more flexible than recompile the program or change the file name in order to use the program

The code below does just that:

- uses `image.raw` as a default for the file name, but allowing you to enter the file name on the command line
- uses `fstat()` to get the file size
- uses a single `fread()` call to read the entire file as a single record

#### A test using the original program file as input:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        20/07/2021     17:40           1067 main.c   
                                                                                                                                                   
PS > gcc -Wall -o tst main.c
PS > ./tst main.c
File is "main.c". Size is 1067 bytes
File "main.c" loaded in memory.
PS > ./tst xys
File is "xys". Could not open: No such file or directory
```

#### The C example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    const char* default_file = "image.raw";
    char    f_name[256];
    if (argc < 2)
        strcpy(f_name, default_file);
    else
        strcpy(f_name, argv[1]);

    FILE* F = fopen(f_name, "rb");
    if (F == NULL)
    {
        printf("File is \"%s\". ", f_name);
        perror("Could not open");
        return -1;       
    }
    struct stat info;
    fstat(_fileno(F),&info);
    printf("File is \"%s\". Size is %lu bytes\n", f_name, info.st_size);

    uint16_t* image = malloc(info.st_size);
    if (image == NULL)
    {   perror("malloc() error");
        return -2;
    };

    if (fread(image, info.st_size, 1, F) != 1)
    {   perror("read error");
        free(image);
        return -3;
    };

    // use 'image'
    printf("File \"%s\" loaded in memory.\n", f_name);
    free(image);
    fclose(F);
    return 0;
}
```